# Qt check if mouse in bounding rect of QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, qmouseevent

I want to drag `GQraphicsPixmapItem` by clicking on any point inside bounding rect of the pixmap. The problem is if the pixmap has transparent parts (png images), then the item does not receive mouse events unless mouse is on top of actual image:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem * item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmapPNG);
item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
```

How to get mouse events when mouse on top of transparent part? Or efficiently check whether mouse is inside the bounding rect?

Example of image

[image]

Comment: You could add the image with transparency so you can test it